# center joomla menu without changing the responsive template

Tags: html, css, joomla

I can not get the menu div centered inside the header without changing the responsive menu structure.

I use a template from JA and the client wants to have the logo centered above the menu

I was able to get the logo centered within the main div but the menu is sticking to the left and i think i tried almost every possible solution.

here is the link to the site

http://dev.turnim.com/clients/antonio_j3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option..

```
.nav-collapse.collapse {
    text-align: center;
}
.t3-megamenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Tested in the browser.. it works.